# Arduino's "Upload Using Programmer" for ATmega328 (not ATmega328P)

Tags: arduino, avr, programmer, avrdude, bootloader

I am using the the Atmega328 (not the Atmega328P that is standard with Arduino) on a breadboard version of the Arduino.  I am able to get the bootloader on the Atmega328 using [these](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=58670.0#subject_701645) instructions.  In summary, you add a new entry for the 328 to the `avrdude.conf` file and the `boards.txt` file.

Then, I am able to get my program on the chip by going to `Tools>Board` and setting it to  `Arduino Uno w/ ATmega328 (non-P)` then burning the bootloader on the chip using the 328 config files with the [AVR Pocket Programmer](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=58670.0#subject_701645).  Then I go to `Tools>Board` and switch it to `Arduino Uno` and upload the program using the normal USB connection.

Now, my question is about using the `File>Upload Using Programmer` functionality.  When I do this for the the Atmega328p on a fresh chip everything works.  However, when I try it for the Atmega328, with the IDE set to upload to `Arduino Uno` it throws the error:

```
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA328P is 1E 95 0F
Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.`
```

Is there another config file that has to be changed to enable the "Upload Using Programmer" functionality on other chips?  If anyone has some tips on where to look it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit1:

I also tried setting the IDE to `Arduino Uno w/ ATmega328 (non-P)` and it throws this error:

```
unknown MCU 'atmega328' specified
Known MCU names:
   avr2
   at90s2313
   at90s2323
   at90s2333
   at90s2343
   attiny22
   attiny26
   at90s4414
   at90s4433
   at90s4434
   at90s8515
   at90c8534
   at90s8535
   avr25
   attiny13
   attiny13a
   attiny2313
   attiny24
   attiny44
   attiny84
   attiny25
   attiny45
   attiny85
   attiny261
   attiny461
   attiny861
   attiny43u
   attiny48
   attiny88
   at86rf401
   avr3
   at43usb320
   at43usb355
   at76c711
   avr31
   atmega103
   avr35
   at90usb82
   at90usb162
   attiny167
   avr4
   atmega8
   atmega48
   atmega48p
   atmega88
   atmega88p
   atmega8515
   atmega8535
   atmega8hva
   at90pwm1
   at90pwm2
   at90pwm2b
   at90pwm3
   at90pwm3b
   avr5
   atmega16
   atmega161
   atmega162
   atmega163
   atmega164p
   atmega165
   atmega165p
   atmega168
   atmega168p
   atmega169
   atmega169p
   atmega32
   atmega323
   atmega324p
   atmega325
   atmega325p
   atmega3250
   atmega3250p
   atmega328p
   atmega329
   atmega329p
   atmega3290
   atmega3290p
   atmega406
   atmega64
   atmega640
   atmega644
   atmega644p
   atmega645
   atmega6450
   atmega649
   atmega6490
   atmega16hva
   at90can32
   at90can64
   at90pwm216
   at90pwm316
   atmega32m1
   atmega32c1
   atmega32u4
   atmega32u6
   at90usb646
   at90usb647
   at94k
   avr51
   atmega128
   atmega1280
   atmega1281
   atmega1284p
   at90can128
   at90usb1286
   at90usb1287
   avr6
   atmega2560
   atmega2561
   avrxmega4
   atxmega64a3
   avrxmega5
   atxmega64a1
   avrxmega6
   atxmega128a3
   atxmega256a3
   atxmega256a3b
   avrxmega7
   atxmega128a1
   avr1
   at90s1200
   attiny11
   attiny12
   attiny15
   attiny28
Blink:-1: error: MCU 'atmega328' supported for assembler only
```

Edit2:  [Here](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,112122.0.html) is another person with the same problem but without an answer.

Comment: This error is from avr-gcc.  You may be able to find a version which supports the 328; otherwise the differences are quite minor so you might be able to tell avr-gcc that you have a 328p, and either tell avrdude the truth, or use the -F flag so it doesn't fail when the signature mismatches.

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for your help!  Is there a way for me to get the Arduino IDE to tell me what command it is running?  Or to just get more info about what it is doing behind the curtain so that I might be able to reconfigure it?  I have been able to get things working by using the command line with avrdude.  To get this working I modified the avrdude.conf file then fed in the program outputted by the Arduino IDE.  It worked!  But it would be better if could get it working in the IDE...

Comment: To get it working, I did download a new version of avrdude and did not use the one that seems to be bundled with Arduino

Comment: Sorry, I rarely use the IDE

Comment: Do you mostly use avrdude in the command line?  Do you happen to know the commands that the IDE is using?  I tried the "verify button" + "shift key" to get verbose but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the shift key + verify is no longer used.  It is now a tick box in settings... I have more info to go off of now and am looking into it..

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly solve the problem by trying the following variant of your approach:

Edit avrdude.conf (located in \hardware\tools\avr\etc) by going to the Atmega328P entry and then replacing "0x1e 0x95 0x0F" with "0x1e 0x95 0x14".

In other words, REPLACE Atmega328P's expected signature with that of Atmega328 (i.e., NOT make a separate entry, but instead actually replace... so as to essentially attempt to trick the IDE).

Be sure to restart the Arduino IDE after saving the .conf file.

Now, continue with "Upload using programmer", with Atmega328P board (i.e., the original) selected.

If that fails, you may instead use an FTDI board/cable to upload, if circumstances allow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have arrived too late (like 10 years) but maybe this will be useful in the future. There is an interesting library for this job:

https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore

This library lets you many flashing options (different crystals, mcus, BDO, etc).